# Como passar dados de duas tabelas em uma View?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Estou tentando passar dados de duas tabelas(`SQL`) em uma estrutura de tabela `HTML`. Quando tento passar pra minha `View`, o `Laravel` não reconhece o método da relação.

`View` - `atualizador.blade.php`

```
@extends('layouts.sidebar')
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')


<table class="table">

  <table style="width:80%; margin-left: 10%;">
 <tr>

   <th>Imagem</th>
   <th>Código</th>
   <th>Produto</th>
   <th>Custo</th>
   <th>Preço</th>
   <th>Atualização</th>
   <th>Status</th>
   <th>Estoque</th>
   <th>Distruibuidor</th>
   <th>Ações</th>
 </tr>
 <tr>
   @foreach($produtos as $produto)
   <td>Imagem</td>
   <td>{{$produto->erp_productid}}</td>

  <td>{{$produto->produtosdescricao->erp_name}}</td>
   <td>{{$produto->erp_cost}}</td>
   <td>{{$produto->erp_price}}</td>
   <td>{{$produto->erp_modifieddate}}</td>
   <td>{{$produto->erp_status}}</td>
   <td>{{$produto->erp_quantity}}</td>
   <td>{{$produto->erp_distributor}}</td>
   <td></td>

 </tr>

@endforeach
</table>
</table>
<center>{{$produtos->links()}}</center>
@endsection
```

`Controller` - `ProdutosController.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Produtos;
use App\ProdutosDescricao;

class ProdutosController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      $id = 3;
      $produtos = DB::table('erp_product')
                    ->paginate(25);
      $p = Produtos::find(3);
      return view('atualizador')
              ->with('produtos', $produtos)
              ->with('p', $p);
    }
}
```

`Model` - `Produtos.php`

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Produtos extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'erp_product';
    protected $primaryKey = 'erp_productid';

    public function produtosdescricao()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\ProdutosDescricao', 'erp_name');
    }
}
```

`Rota`

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/atualizador', 'ProdutosController@index');
Route::get('/atualizaBanco', 'HomeController@atualiza');
Route::get('/insereBanco', 'HomeController@insere');
```

O código retorna o ***erro***:

> `Undefined property: stdClass::$produtosdescricao (View: C:\comerciourbano\resources\views\atualizador.blade.php)`

Alguma sugestão?

Comment: Como está a tua relação produtos/produtosdescricao?

Comment: Olá, Miguel, eu declarei como hasOne na Produtos e na Model ProdutosDescricao: `<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class ProdutosDescricao extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'erp_product_description';
    protected $primaryKey = 'erp_productid';

    public function produto()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('App\Produtos');
    }
} `

Comment: Mas aí tens `belongsTo`, não tens `hasOne`, e deves fazer o mesmo no model do produto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça assim:

Em vez de utilizar a `classe` [DB](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database) utilize a `classe` `Produtos`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
use App\Produtos;
use App\ProdutosDescricao;

class ProdutosController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
      $id = 3;
      $produtos = Produtos::with('produtosdescricao')
                           ->paginate(25);

      $p = Produtos::find(3);
      return view('atualizador')
              ->with('produtos', $produtos)
              ->with('p', $p);
    }
}
```

dessa forma os dados são carregados (inclusive com bom desempenho) para a sua `View`.

*Na relação, precisaria ver como estão configuradas as suas tabelas.*

<sub>***Referencias:***</sub>

- [Database: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/database)
- [Eloquent: Getting Started](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent)

Comment: Você falou **"inclusive com bom desempenho"** no caso do uso de `return view('my.view', compact('var1', 'var2')`. É menos performático?

Comment: @Luitame não é nesse ponto é no ponto aonde você quer utilizar uma técnica que não existe no `DB`, mas, sim no `Eloquent` que é o carregamento na hora de acessar o método isso não é performático, é nesse aspecto. Exatamente aqui: `<td>{{$produto->produtosdescricao->erp_name}}</td>`, quando utiliza o `with` é performático, quando não se utiliza não é porque a cada interação é gerado um nova SQL e com `with` são somente duas `SQL`.

Comment: Obrigado Virgilio Novic, fiz do jeito que você falou e deu certo!

Comment: @ViniciusRosa não esqueça do aceitar com resposta.

Comment: @ViniciusRosa massa eu perguntei não como hater e sim pra aprender com seu feedback, pois fiquei curioso. Eu também utilizo o Laravel em uns projetos.

Comment: @Luitame eu comecei utilizando Laravel na faculdade, mas não me aprofundei muito, ainda tenho muitas dificuldades, mas com o tempo to pegando o jeito, se você tiver interesse em formar algum grupo pra que a gente possa trocar ideia sobre a plataforma, eu aceito :)

Comment: @ViniciusRosa já existem grupos com bastante volume e qualidade. Procura por Laravel Brasil. Tem no Telegram, Slack e até no forum no Github. Já estou por lá junte-se a tribo.